# Accessing methods of class object that it's in a vector

Tags: c++, class, vector, methods

Ok so i have a class `class person` and i have a `vector<person>group` that saves different objects from the `class person`. Also the `class person` has the method `void getName()` that gets the name. My question is how can i search the vector so i can use the method for the specific object ?

Comment: What did you try and how does it fail? If you have no clue, then try `std::find_if`

Comment: Please elaborate more, are you trying to find a particular person? If so, you could just have a `<map>` containing the person's name as the key with the `person` as the key-value

Comment: i want to use a `vector` not a `<map>` and also when i use `find` or `find if` i get errors about semantic issues . To be more specific this is an example of what i want to do.

Comment: `void Get_person(list_reserve input)   //this is a class object
    {
        itr = find (reserve.begin(), reserve.end(), input);
        if (itr != reserve.end()){
            reserve.at(0).getName();
        }
        
    }`

Comment: put it in your post, and to be honest, can't really understand your problem

Comment: Why would a function named `getName` be `void`?! It should return `std::string`.